# Talend: How to get instance of a component in tjava

Tags: talend, data-integration, data-mapping

I want ask if there is way to get an instance of a component if a job (ex:tmap, tmysqlinput) in tjava code and then manipulate it manually using code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Very hazardous. Looking at the generated Java code will give you some answers (I think so).
In fact, accessing to some objects properties is possible (there is blogs and articles about this) but changing anything seems to be dangerous (IMHO).

TRF